# Qooxdoo: данные из отдаленного сервера при помощи JSONP?

Tags: qooxdoo

Как забрать данные из отдаленного сервера?
Доброго времени суток! Знакомлюсь с Qooxdoo в рамках одного проекта в институте и уже третий день не могу достать данные от присланого сервером ответа:
Ответ Сервера (geonames.org): 
qx.bom.request.Jsonp[1338290822798073].callback({"postalCodes":[{"adminCode3":"05554","adminName2":"Reg.-Bez. Münster","adminName3":"Borken","adminCode2":"055","adminCode1":"NW","postalCode":"46397","countryCode":"DE","lng":6.62416666666667,"placeName":"Bocholt","lat":51.8412666666667,"adminName1":"Nordrhein-Westfalen"}]});
Из него мне только нужно "placeName":"Bocholt" в

Мой код:

var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch"+"JSON?username=***&country=DE&postalcode="+
        escape(plzTextfield.getValue());

var request = new qx.bom.request.Jsonp(url, null, "getLocation");
    request.onReadyStateChange = getLocation;

```
request.open("GET",url);
request.send();

var postalcode;
```

function getLocation(jData){
        if (request.readyStateChange == 4){
            if (request.getStatus == 200){

```
            postalcode = jData.postalCodes;
            var placeInput = new qx.ui.basic.Label();
            placeInput.getValue() = postalcode[0].placeName;
            page1.add(placeInput, {row: 3, column: 3});

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ(ы)!
Решила другим способом - поменяла req: 
var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch"+"JSON?username=****&output=jsonp&country=DE&postalcode="+ postalcode; 
   var req = new qx.bom.request.Jsonp();
   req.open("GET", url);
   req.send();
      
   req.onload = function getLocation() {
        var doc = req.responseJson;   
        var ort = doc.postalCodes[0];
        var ortInput =   new qx.ui.basic.Label()
            ortInput.setValue(ort.placeName);
        page1.add(ortInput, {row: 3, column: 4});   
       
   }

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут все немного сложнее...
Обратите внимание, что "qx.bom.request.Jsonp" должен принять json соответствующий формату.
Т.е. должна вызываться каллбэчная функция, аргументом которой будет json с нужными Вами параметрами.

ПРимер ответа от сервера:

qx.bom.request.JsonP.callback({"counrty": 123})

В qooxdoo должна быть описана эта функция. qx.bom.request.JsonP.callback(json)

Как я понимаю, у Вас и проблема - данные возвращаются, а в строке - пустота :) Но, боюсь, что если Вы не можете сделать отдать на сервер имя функции, которую должен будет запустить QX при получении ответа (чтобы обратный json был нужного формата) - боюсь, тут ничего поделать будет нельзя. Хотя.... все возможно :)